# How to read special characters encoded in UTF-8 in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, mysql-connector

I was trying to extract some data from mysql database using python, But I have problem with special characters (the data are strings in FR, ES, De and IT languages). Whenever a word has a special character (like an accent á ñ etc.) are no encoded properly in the file (I'm creating a csv with the extracted data)
This is the code I was using

```
import mysql.connector
if __name__ == '__main__':

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='psswrd',
                              host='slave',
                              database='DB',
                              buffered=True)
    us_id_list = ['496305']

    f = open('missing_cat_mappings.csv', 'w')
    for (us_id) in us_id_list:
        print us_id
        mapping_cursor = cnx.cursor()
        query = (format(user_id=us_id,))
        success = False
        fails = 0
        while not success:
            try:
                print "try" + str(fails)
                mapping_cursor.execute(query)
                success = True
            except:
                fails += 1
                if fails > 10:
                    raise

        for row in mapping_cursor:
            f.write(str(row) + "\n")

        mapping_cursor.close()
    f.close()

    cnx.close()
```

I added:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# vim: set fileencoding=<UTF-8> :
```

at the beggining but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Nowhere in the code do you specify that the encoding is utf-8 so how should python know?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to `open` the CSV file in binary mode, `'wb'` not text mode `'w'`